# json parse error: invalid char in json text

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, yajl

I faced with a problem parsing json file with yajl-ruby.
It shows an error of this kind:

`'parse': lexical error: invalid char in json text. (Yajl::ParseError)`

> ```
>                    {     "inquiry":         {         "
> (right here) ------^
> ```

I have tried to open a file with utf-8 encoding explicitly, but it doesn't help.
The strange part of it that it raises error on a curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that I have opened a file encoded in **UTF-8 with BOM**.
To fix this error, I was needed to open a file with following options:

`File.open(@file, 'r:bom|utf-8')`